# Is $m\sim n \iff m\leq n$ an equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I have a problem that asks

> decide which ones of the three properties (symmetric, reflexive, transitive) are true for each of the following relations in the set of all positive integers.

the one I'm working on is $m\sim n \iff m\leq n$. Now, the teacher posted solutions saying it is reflexive and transitive, but not symmetric. I am confused because I thought it was symmetric. My reasoning is that while $n$ cannot be less than $m$, the equality still holds, i.e. if $m\leq n$, $n\leq m$ is also true when $n=m$. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Symmetric" would mean *absolutely every time you have* $m \sim n$, you *must* have $n \sim m$. Notice that, for example, $1 \leq 2$; so $1 \sim 2$, by definition. But $2 \nleq 1$, so $2 \nsim 1$.

Certainly **if** $n = m$, symmetry holds; but when you're talking about equivalence relations, you don't get to add qualifiers like "if $n = m$".

Comment: Thank you, your response is very clear

Answer (score 2):

Symmetric means $\forall m \forall n [m \le n \to n \le m]$, which is clearly false.

What that means is that it needs to work for all $m$ and $n$, not just those that are equal.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now